# How do I sort an array of structs via member NSDate objects?

Tags: sorting, struct, swift2

How do I sort (ascending) an array of structs per member NSDate?

```
struct TimelineItem {
    var creationDate:NSDate?
    var itemImage:UIImage?
    var itemDescription:NSAttributedString?
    var itemType:timelineType
    var photoURLStrings:[String]?
    var videoURLStrings:[String]?
    init(creationDate:NSDate, itemImage:UIImage, itemDescription:NSAttributedString, itemType:timelineType) {
        self.creationDate = creationDate
        self.itemImage = itemImage
        self.itemDescription = itemDescription
        self.itemType = itemType
    }
}

var gTimelineItems:[TimelineItem] = []
```

I want to do something like:

```
gTimelineItems.sort { $1.creationDate! > $1.creationDate! }
```

But I get the error that Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to two NSDate operands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSDate` doesn't implement the `Comparable` protocol. Try this:

```
gTimelineItems.sort { $0.creationDate!.timeIntervalSince1970 > $1.creationDate!.timeIntervalSince1970 }
```

Comment: I used the modified 'sortInPlace'.  Looks Good!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Zoff, I used the modified 'sortInPlace':

```
gTimelineItems.sortInPlace { $0.creationDate!.timeIntervalSince1970 > $1.creationDate!.timeIntervalSince1970 }
```